# Uniqueness of product measure

Tags: probability-theory

I am now confused by the proof of uniqueness of product measure in my course's notes.

Here's the setup

> Consider two measurable spaces $(\Omega _{1},\mathscr F_{1}),(\Omega _{2},\mathscr F_{2})$. The Cartesian product $$\Omega=\left \{ {(\omega_{1},\omega_{2}):\omega_{1} \in \mathscr F_{1},\omega_{2} \in \mathscr F_{2}}\right \}$$
>
> we define the measurable rectangles $$\mathscr R=\left \{{E_{1} \times E_{2}, E_{1} \in \mathscr F_{1},E_{2} \in \mathscr F_{2}}\right \}$$
>
> We let $\mathscr F$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathscr R$, and the product measure $\Bbb P$ satisfies the following property.$$\Bbb P(E_{1} \times E_{2})=\Bbb P_{1}(E_{1})  \Bbb P_{2}(E_{2})$$ for all $E_{1} \in \mathscr F_{1},E_{2} \in \mathscr F_{2}$, $\Bbb P_{1},\Bbb P_{2}$ are the measures on the two measurable spaces respectively.

My question is that, my notes said if there exists another product measure $\mu$ which satisfy the property above, then $\mu$ and $\Bbb P$ agree on the measurable rectangles $\mathscr R$. I don't know how we get the result since I think we can only get the following
$$\Bbb P(E)=\Bbb P_{1}(E_{1})  \Bbb P_{2}(E_{2})$$
$$ \mu(E)=\mu_{1}(E_{1})  \mu_{2}(E_{2})$$

Could someone help me with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mu_1=P_1$ and $\mu_2=P_2$ in this assertion.

Comment: If $ E_1 \in \mathscr{F}_1 $, what do you mean by $ \mu(E_1) $?

Comment: The assumption is that $\Bbb P_1$ and $\Bbb P_2$ are fixed reference measures, as Kavi Rama Murthy says.

Comment: @Shalop you mean the statement is "suppose there exists another measure $\mu$ that satisfies $\mu(E)=\mu_{1}(E_{1})  \mu_{2}(E_{2})$ and $\mu_{1}=\Bbb P_{1}$,$\mu_{2}=\Bbb P_{2}$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you mean the assertion is "suppose there exists another measure  that satisfies $\mu(E)=\mu_{1}(E_{1})  \mu_{2}(E_{2})$ and $\mu_{1}=\Bbb P_{1}$,$\mu_{2}=\Bbb P_{2}$?

Comment: @Vector Yes, assuming $E=E_1\times E_2$ in your notation